# Why is it required to make Context final in below code?

Tags: java, android

// below code is part of an activity having a listview

private class MyListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

```
public MyListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, R.layout.level_items, cursor);
}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {           

     TextView lev_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_level);
     lev_id.setText("Level " + cursor.getString(
                         cursor.getColumnIndex(PuzzleDBAdapter.KEY_LEVEL_ID)));
     TextView solved = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_solved);
     solved.setText("Solved " + cursor.getString(
                         cursor.getColumnIndex(PuzzleDBAdapter.KEY_SOLVED)));

     TextView score = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_score);
     score.setText("Score " + cursor.getString(
                         cursor.getColumnIndex(PuzzleDBAdapter.KEY_SCORE)));
     Button startBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_start);

     startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Intent intent = new Intent(context, PuzzleActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
     });



}
```

}

I got error on the above code saying: ***Cannot refer to a non-final variable context inside an inner class defined in a different method.*** Though after adding the final keyword before Context on the function bindview() as

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {    //...
```

solved the issue, I need to understand the meaning of the error message. Why can not we refer to the  non final variable context in the above inner class ?

Additionally, is there any side effect making it final?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final` means that the value can be assigned only once.

Local variables are passed to anonymous inner class instances (such as your `OnClickListener`) by means of an auto-generated constructor - you can see it by examining the generated bytecode. So the inner class instance receives a copy of the variable. If the variable wasn't `final`, the original value and its copy could diverge in value. By requiring the `final`on the variable, such problems are avoided.

As for side effects of `final` - it allows the compiler to do certain optimizations by knowing the value cannot change after first assignment.

Answer (score 1):

When the bindView(...) method returns, your local variable will be cleaned up from the stack, so they won't exist anymore. But the anonymous class object new View.OnClickListener() references these variables, so using no constant variables is wrong,so java don't allow you to do this.

After it is final it becomes a constant. So it is storing in the heap and can be safely used in anonymous classes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the context final just replace

```
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, PuzzleActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
```

with

```
         Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PuzzleActivity.class);
         v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

The posters above me explained the reason, here is a solution